Apply CSS in tab Service Message
I would like to know if it is possible to change the style of this tab according to a past tense. The idea is to get redder as time passes, to alert the user that the chat is old.
Is it possible to do? even more so with lwc?


Yes, you can use the setTabHighlighted (Lightning) or setTabStyle (Classic) to control the tab style. Generally speaking, you'd want to build a Utility Bar component that tracks how old the tabs are, and update them using the methods mentioned above.

Hello again! Thanks for responding, after months I'm resuming this project. I'm having difficulties with how to apply and build the lwc, if it's not inconvenient, could you give me an example?
Thank you in advance for your attention.
